# How to implement the celery-rabbitmq-redis on 8 computers

Tags: python

**5.1   Back ground**

Recently, we are handling MRR files (Measurement Result Recording) in the LTE network.  In every hour, we will collect about   thousands of files in the capacity of 2T in my project.  After we have parsed the Xml files we will get about 20 billion sample points every day.  Since we have so many files to handle, we have used the multi-process technology via multi-processors of a single linux computer. Yet the linux computers has only 24 processors, we wish to have several computers to handle the files. 
   The project can be seen here: https://github.com/zengqingbo/mroget.

**5.2   Hardware environment**

```
In the above diagram, we can see that we have three kinds of computers.
```

[image]
1, Filer getter machine: It will connect to various LTE OMC servers, scanning the new arriving MRR files in certain directory and transfer the new arriving files to the local file machine. At present we have just 1 computer.
2、File parser machine：  The new arriving files will be distributed to the file parser machine. The file parser process will fetch the new arriving files , parse the xml files, transfer the file stream into object stream, pick up the required data items and transfer the object stream into the CSV format file stream .  All the required information fields will be recorded in the csv file. In our plan, we will use 7 computers to parse the files.
3、Database machine: All the required information fields will future be uploaded into the database. We choose Green-plums as the database engine.  At present, we have 5 computers to run the Green-plums database instances.

**5.3   Single machine solution**
Recently, we have worked out a prototype to parse the MRR files and copy the final result CSV files into the MPP database. So let us have a look at the single machine solution.

5.3.1   Global component view 
 [image]
         Figure 5-1 the component view of the file-sender 
   First we have a look at the control object. 
1、： filesender:it will look up the new arriving xml files , identify the vender of the XML files ( There five venders in my province,  we choose different approaches to handle the MRR files form different vender.)

2、handleFile： if the MRR files is two-layer compressed file format, we will choose the component handleFile to process the file. The logic to handle the two-layer compressed file is relative complex.

3、handle singlefile： if the MRR files is one-layer compressed file format, we will choose the component handle singlefile to process the file. The logic to handle the one-layer compressed file is relative simple

We have two interface object:

1、getvalidfilelist: it will verify the database to fetch the new arrived MRR files. The information structure will be copied to the object RS.

2、getnbcfgdict: it will visit the database to get the vender associated information.  And the information structure will be copied to the object nbccfg.

The we have two entity objects.

1、nbccfg： the object nbccfg will contain information structure of the LTE OMC FTP server, with the information structure the object Filesender will identity the vender of the MRR xml file, and the id of various omc-server which will future be used as the file segment identity in the local file system.
             [image]

2, RS: the object RS will contain the information structure of the new arrived files.

[image]
With the information, we can identify the file directory of the new arrived file, the file name of the new arrived file, the nid of the new arrived file( the nid represent the source OMC-server which prepares the MRR files)

The above seven objects are the main components to handle the new arrived files. In summary the object fileSender works as the coordinator to schedule the new arrived MRR files, the object handleFile and handleSingleFile will work as the worker to process the new arrived MRR files according to the vender of the MRR files.

**5.3.2 handleFile**

if the MRR files is two-layer compressed file format, we will choose the component handleFile to process the file. The logic to handle the two-layer compressed file is relative complex. Let’s have a look at the component view of the handleFile.

[image]
   Figure 5-2 the component view of handle file 
In the above diagram , we will see the main procedure of the XML processing task.

1、 The object handleZipfile(filename ,nid) will first identify the file directory of the MRR files acoording to the input argument .

2、the object handleZipfile(filename ,nid) will fetch target file and transfer the file stream into the object stream via the function ZIPfile(), we have the object myzip which is the object stream in the memory. In general, the object myzip is in the size of 1 G Byte.

3、the object handleZipfile(filename ,nid) will scan the object myzip,  identify all the sub-zip files and call the function of the multi-pool object to wake up various process to handle the subZIP file.

4、The object  handleSubZip(myzip,subname,nid)  will  parse the subZip file.  And the number of instance of the class handleSubZip(myzip,subname,nid)  depends on the number of processors of the local computer. 
        When all the sub-zip files are handled, the two layers compressed file is finished.

**5.3.3 Handlesinglefile()**

if the MRR files is just one-layer compressed file format, we will choose the component handlesingleFile to process the file. The logic to handle the one-layer compressed file is relative simple. Let’s have a look at the component view of the handleFile.
[image]

In this case , the logic is relative simple, we just call a object  handleMrofile（）to parse the file, which is a component form previous project.

**5.4   The problem we meet**

1, schedule management component:  Now we just use the schedule of the linux os system, we hope to find a python component to manage the task.

2, the coordination of the File getter and the File parser: we have 1 computer to work as the File getter, and 7 computers to work as the File Parser. We still do not find a proper way to coordinate the 8 computers.

3, how to collecting the logs for the computers and process: in the distributing environment, it is so difficult to collect the log for the each of  control  component. For example, in the File parser computers, there are about 300 process to parse the files in concurrence. That will be difficult.

**5.5   The celery approach**

And  early this year, we found a solution I follow the GIT-project ：https://github.com/esperdyne/celery-message-processing.

[image]
We have run the project in 1 machine, yet I do not know how can I adapt the solution in the multi-computer environment.   Hope a friend to help me to adapt the solution to a multi-computer environment?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a Redis server and [configuring Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html) to use it as a broker on multiple machines? RabbitMQ is also an [option](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, we use the RabbitMQ as the broker.  I just do not know if we set up a RabbitMQ server, how can the wokers in the 8 machine to share the message!

Comment: Just point Celery to your broker and run it on multiple machines.

Comment: What is more, if you have a solution of the redis server, could you please show me the solution. in the project  https://github.com/esperdyne/celery-message-processing., redis is used ad the backend.  see the configure file:backend='redis://localhost ',

Comment: I posted a link to both in the first comment. It's the same basic concept. You install the broker server, make sure it's accessible to all relevant machines, point Celery to the broker, and start Celery on all the relevant machines.

Comment: oh, may I say, I will install the celery components in each of the seven machine? and the various celery instance which is located in various machine will reference to the same rabbit-mq servers?       the problem is I have a flle parser component, I have to distributed the component in seven machine, so I just do know the mode to set up the message?

Comment: Yes. Just reference the same RabbitMQ server. Your message should contain information that will allow your file parser to access its data but not the 2TB of data itself.

Comment: oh ,the approach seems might work, would you please let me know your email, if I find out the answer , I hope to email you my component view of the project!

Comment: I have upload a repository,https://github.com/zengqingbo/mroget; hope you can take a time to help me to figure out the component view!